# Can Java's DatagramSockets become invalid or can they be used forever without problems?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

We are using a DatagramSocket to send messages over UDP. Currently we use the following code.

```
private void doSend() throws IOException, SocketException {
    try (DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket()) {
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(messageBytes, messageBytes.length, address,
                port);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
}
```

As you can see we re-create the `DatagramSocket` for each message. For performance reasons we are considering creating the socket only once instead of for each message. The code lives in a long lived object so this would mean the socket is alive for several days.

My question is whether the `DatagramSocket` can become invalid through some error and must be re-created or if we can simply create the socket one time and be done with it? If it can become invalid and must be re-created, how can we detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things that invalidate a `DatagramSocket` are:

1. Closing it. Using it in this state will cause a `SocketException: socket closed.`
2. A bind failure. Using it in this state will probably cause a default bind() to happen, to 0.0.0.0:0, which will yield a system-allocated port, which may not be what you want.
3. Connecting it to an invalid address, in which case sends may fail and receives will do nothing: you can recover from that via `disconnect()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This would mean that in our case 1) is no problem, we have control over when it is closed. 2) is no problem since the bind happens at creation time. 3) would not be a problem either since we do not connect it.